# No me cargan las Imagenes de mi proyecto de NextJS13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs

Realice un proyecto para una empresa, donde utilice Nextjs y TailwindCSS, resulta que de manera local el proyecto funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo voy a montar al CPANEL, las imagenes no me cargan. Sinceramente el el primer proyecto que hago desde 0 y no tengo conocimiento de muchas cosas. Cabe aclarar que la empresa tiene una VPS, donde se montan los archivos.

Para poder montar el proyecto en la ruta /public del dominio, tuve que editar el archivo "next.config.js", agregandole lo siguiente:

```
const nextConfig = {output: "export", distDir: "dist",};
```

Para que cuando corriera el comando "npm run build" me creara la carpeta dist donde me genera los archivos estaticos.

Dentro de la ruta "dist_next\static\media" puedo ver las imagenes, pero me genera duda al momento de revisar las rutas de las imagenes en los archivos .html que se generaron, pues primero que nada no aparece "src" sino "srcSet" y las rutas no son las convencionales.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con el tema le agradeceria un monton.

Este es el link del [repositorio](https://github.com/mundevux/impulsa-colombia-sas).

Answer (score 0):

Como la página es estática por el `output: "export"`, deberás agregar

```
images: {
    unoptimized:true
}
```

Dejando las imágenes no optomizadas ya que no cuentas con el servidor si no solo los archivos estaticos del cliente.

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351068/nextjs-images-are-not-shown-using-export-script#answers